# Closing dijitDialog Dialog using Watir

Tags: javascript, selenium, dojo, watir

Using Watir/Selenium, I'm looking to click the 'Cancel' button in the top right corner of the dialog, like so:
[dijitDialog 'Cancel'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t51lh.png)

Below is the DOM:

```
<div class="dijitDialog" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dijit_Dialog_4_title" id="dijit_Dialog_4" widgetid="dijit_Dialog_4" style="width: 300px; position: absolute; opacity: 1; left: 533px; top: 297px; z-index: 100000;">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="dijit_Dialog_4_title" role="heading" level="1">Info</span>
        

 - <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode"
   class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:
   onCancel" title="Cancel" role="button" tabindex="-1">

            <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText" title="Cancel">x</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent"><img src="information.gif" style="vertical-align:bottom">  Approved 1 record(s)</div>
    
</div>
```

I'm thinking that something along the lines of: `browser.element(name: "nameOfButton").click` needs to be used, but I'm not sure.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would try either:

```
browser.span(class: 'dijitDialogCloseIcon').click
```

or

```
browser.span(data_dojo_attach_point: 'closeButtonNode').click
```

Note that depending how many of these close/cancel links exist on the page, you might need to scope the locator to the dialog (rather than the entire browser) and/or include the `:visible` locator.

Comment: This works, thank you. I figured that you could exit the dialog by clicking the 'escape' key, so I used that instead.